# Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'

Tags: javascript

Estoy revisando un proyecto que se creó en el 2016. Revisando el código el depurador de Firefox me señala que hay un error:

> ```js
>    Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'
>        jQuery 14
>        verlistadoa http://localhost/aam/vistas/js/funcion_cal_a.js:11
>        jQuery 7
>        verlistadoa http://localhost/aam/vistas/js/funcion_cal_a.js:8
>        <anonymous> http://localhost/aam/vistas/js/funcion_cal_a.js:3
> ```

Revisé el archivo y las líneas donde me marca el error y si digamos que encontré una omisión sobre la referencia que me indica Firefox.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    verlistadoa()
    
})
function verlistadoa(){ 

            $.post("libsfile/list_cal_cat_a.php", {
            }, function(data){
              $("#calCategoriaA").html(data);
            });
}
```

una vez revisada la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_semicolon_before_statement) modifiqué el script en base a este señalamiento:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    verlistadoa();  <<-- se añadio el ;
    
})
function verlistadoa(){ 

            $.post("libsfile/list_cal_cat_a.php", {
            }, function(data){
              $("#calCategoriaA").html(data);
            });
}
```

Sin embargo me sigue señalando lo mismo.

¿Me podrían echar la mano a identificar donde se supone que hace falta añadir otra `;`? porque de verdad estoy como se dice que se tiene una  "ceguera de taller".

Comment: El punto y coma final normalmente no es imprescindible en javascript, no hace falta usarlo siempre ni mucho menos. Yo solo lo uso cuando escribo instrucciones seguidas en la misma línea, para separarlas, pero nada más que yo recuerde ahora.  Dicho esto, el error del `unexpected token: ':'` te indica que ha encontrado unos dos puntos `:` en algun lugar inesperado de tu archivo `funcion_cal_a.js`, y no se si se corresponde con lo que has pegado aquí, pero yo no los veo escritos en tu pregunta en ningún lugar, por lo que dudo que ese código que has puesto tenga relación con el problema.

Comment: @Fedex7501 he borrado comentarios para limpiar la zona de ruido... te recomiendo hacer lo mismo :-) saludos